# how to create common interface to access 2 different ocx's using c#

Tags: c#, .net, interface, activex, ocx

I have 2 OCX's with 2 different versions. These are 3rd party ocx's. Each ocx have set of methods, properties and events which are almost same in both the version except few. I compile my projects twice for publishing. So I have 2 click once deployments - one with version 1 and another with version 2. I ask my users to use version if they have version 1 software installed on their system and so on.

I would like to know if there is a way where I compile and deploy only one version of my application and depending in the version of 3rd party software installed on user's system, my application will pickup that ocx version during runtime?

Or is there a way I implement an interface where I code/inherit all properties, methods and events and do a late binding?
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use container like Structure Map or Castle or AutoFac.

When your app will start it will determine if the 3party software is installed and fill the container wiht proper implementation of an interfaces. Than when you will need the class object you call the container to give it to you.

You can use service locator pattern (static class to container) - it is simpler and requires less work but makes your code tied up to a container implementation or if you want you can resolve all classes at startup of your app.

Give it a try, there is a lot of help to this online.

Comment: I am new to the above described IoC's. Could you please point me to some links. I tried searching but the search results I am getting are not explanatory.